# Adding to Fragment ArrayAdapter from Activity AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I'm learning to prototype in Android Studio, and I've reached a snag for which I can't seem to find any answers.

I have an Activity that displays a custom ArrayAdapter as a ListView. I can edit the items in the ListView by clicking on them and typing into the resulting AlertDialog. There's also an add button which I can press, and it brings up a similar AlertDialog, but when I hit save nothing gets added to the ListView. How do I get the AlertDialog text input to save as a new ArrayAdapter item?

Most examples I've found have instantiated the ArrayAdapter directly in the Activity, rather than through a Fragment the way I've done it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //initialize the activity
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //establish where the layout will come from
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //creates a toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        //creates the first fragment dynamically, so it can be replaced
        Fragment firstFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }

    //This creates the Floating Action Button
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createDialog();
        }

        private void createDialog() {
            ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

            // create an AlertDialog that'll come up when the add button is clicked
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            // set title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Add item");

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this); //uses the EditText from dialog_set
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT); //makes the dialog ask for plain text input
            alertDialog.setView(input);

            // set up buttons

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String textInput = input.getText().toString(); //saves user text as a string
                    Log.d(TAG, textInput); // records input as a log
                    CustomUsersAdapter.this.add(textInput);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.lvUsers) ListView listView;

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 1", "Hometown 1"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 2", "Hometown 2"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 3", "Hometown 3"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 4", "Hometown 4"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 5", "Hometown 5"));
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    CustomUsersAdapter adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter(getContext(), arrayOfUsers);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

**CustomUsersAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
private ArrayList<User> users;

public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
    this.users = users;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    User user = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvName.setText(user.name);
    tvHome.setText(user.hometown);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createDialog(position);
        }
    });

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

protected void add(String textInput) {
    add(new User(textInput, "Incomplete"));
}

private void createDialog(final int position) {
    // create an AlertDialog that'll come up when text is clicked
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getContext());

    // set title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Edit item");

    final EditText input = new EditText(getContext()); //uses the EditText from dialog_set
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT); //makes the dialog ask for plain text input
    alertDialog.setView(input);

    // set up buttons

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String textInput = input.getText().toString(); //saves user text as a string
            users.get(position).name = textInput;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Complete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            users.get(position).hometown = "Complete";
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**ListView layout (from fragment_main.xml)**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvUsers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: `I can edit the items in the ArrayAdapter by clicking on them`. Impossible. An array adapter is no gui element, no view, so unclickable. Please rephrase.

Comment: Is there a reason you have the FAB in the activity vs. the fragment?

Comment: @greenapps, I changed the wording a bit - is it clearer now?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai, no? It was already in the activity (I used the template that had a FAB already included) and like I said, I'm learning, so I've been using what I have available to me. Would moving the FAB to the fragment be useful?

Comment: `that displays a custom ArrayAdapter as an ArrayList. I can edit the items in the ArrayList by clicking on them`. Impossible too. An array list is invisible. It is no gui element. It is no view. So you cannot click on it. Please try again.

Comment: @greenapps there's an OnClickListener set up in CustomUsersAdapter...is that what you're looking for? You can see that in my code and I'm really not sure what more I need to say/how this in particular is relevant to the question I asked...

Comment: It is relevant for the way a programmer talks about what he is doing. And the way you post a problem here. And you said `I am learning` . A user can only click on a gui element. A `view`. In your case he clicks an item in a `ListView`. So i hoped you would have told that finally as i twice mentioned `view'. For every element in your array list there is an item in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues that you have. First off, you are attempting to update your adapter using a static call, but you can't do that. You also need to adjust your `add` method. It should look something like:

```
protected void add(String textInput) {
    this.users.add(new User(textInput, "Incomplete"));
}
```

This is only part of the issue though. You need to pass an object reference into the `onClickListener`. You are trying to make a static call. This won't work. I might think about putting the Floating Action Button. If you did that, then you could easily pass the reference to adapter:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private final CustomUsersAdapter adapter;
@BindView(R.id.lvUsers) ListView listView;


public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 1", "Hometown 1"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 2", "Hometown 2"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 3", "Hometown 3"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 4", "Hometown 4"));
    arrayOfUsers.add(new User("Person 5", "Hometown 5"));
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
   adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter(getContext(), arrayOfUsers);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

//This creates the Floating Action Button
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createDialog();
        }

        private void createDialog() {
            ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

            // create an AlertDialog that'll come up when the add button is clicked
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            // set title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Add item");

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this); //uses the EditText from dialog_set
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT); //makes the dialog ask for plain text input
            alertDialog.setView(input);

            // set up buttons

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String textInput = input.getText().toString(); //saves user text as a string
                    Log.d(TAG, textInput); // records input as a log
                   adapter.add(textInput);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

By doing something like this, you can pass the reference to the adapter into the inner-class that you created, and then update it. Hope this helps.